# What the context should i set in AlertDialog.Builder constructor?

Tags: android, cordova, alert

That the code I try to do but occur an error,
the error said in builder cannot be applied to (anonymous `android.widget.Popupmenu.OnMenuItemClickListener`)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HalakaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(halakat.get(position));
    holder.imgbtn_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.halaka_more_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                    switch (id){
                        case R.id.menu_more_halaka_tadel:
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_more_halaka_delete:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're writing it in recyclerview adapter?

Comment: Try using `view.getContext()` instead of `this`

Comment: Karan Mehata , yes i use it in recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You follow this code.

```
holder.itemView.getContext()
```

Comment: and how i can to infalt acustom layout ?

Comment: You have another error here  PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view); you need to set context as holder.itemView.getContext()

Comment: Thank's, Do you know how to inflat layout in first case?

Answer (score 0):

You should create global Context object.

```
private Context context;
```

Then set value to context variable.

```
@Override
public HalakaViewHolder.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  context = parent.getContext();
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, parent, false);
  return new HalakaViewHolder.ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Finally, use it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HalakaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(halakat.get(position));
    holder.imgbtn_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.halaka_more_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                    switch (id){
                        case R.id.menu_more_halaka_tadel:
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_more_halaka_delete:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank's. Do you know how to inflat layout in first case?

Comment: I added inflate block in OnCreateViewHolder method.

Comment: I need to view the layout when i click the item in the popupmenu

Comment: Ok. Add button element "android:focusable = true" attribute in layout. Actually, this code block isn't wrong.